# sqlcmd command and PHP can't connect to SQL Server instance running in a Docker container on a Mac

Tags: sql-server, docker, azure-sql-edge

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server instance running in a Docker container on my Mac using sqlcmd, but I'm getting an "I/O timeout" error. Here's what I've tried so far:

I ran the following command to start the container:

```
docker run --name sql -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Password123' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

I ran the following command to get the container's IP address:

`docker inspect sql | grep IPAddress`,

which returned: "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"

I tried to connect to the SQL Server instance using the following command:
`sqlcmd -S tcp:172.17.0.2,1433 -U sa`, but I got the following error message: `unable to open tcp connection with host '172.17.0.2:1433': dial tcp 172.17.0.2:1433: i/o timeout`

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "172.17.0.2,1433";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "inart",
    "Uid" => "SA",
    "PWD" => "Password123"
);

// Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

// Checks the connection
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to SQL Server." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true) . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to SQL Server was made!" . PHP_EOL;

// Closes the connection
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

When I run this code, it says "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in /a.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /a.php on line 10"

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, then why are you using the MySQLi library? That, as its name suggests, is for MySQL.

Comment: @ThomA what about sqlcmd?

Comment: That's a command line tool.

Comment: no i meant why sqlcmd can't conenct to the sql server

Comment: Why not use `localhost` for the connection? In your docker command you have already set up port forwarding on port 1433 on the localhost.

Comment: You're making things hard for yourself by not using Docker Compositions - the default Docker network doesn't have DNS support for inter-container name resolution. So, it depends on where you're running the `sqlcmd` and your PHP code. If running on the Docker host itself then use `127.0.0.1` (`::1` for IPv6 doesn't always work, and for the same reason `localhost` doesn't always work if IPv6 is involved). If running inside a Docker container then use `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: Aside... are you sure your container is running? Instead of `SA_PASSWORD` [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge) says you should be using `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD`.